# How do I store the Twitter id in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, twitter

The Twitter seach API returns a JSON object, a.o. containing the unique id of a tweet:

```
[id] => 2.9851634017882E+17
[text] => foobar
```

I have created a MySQL `bigint(20)` field in my database to store the id's. However, when I try to store the id, in the database it only says `2` in (in this instance).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every id in the call, I would recommend an approach of converting the value to a string before sending it over to PHP.

I'm doing this with my own webapp and it works great. I faced the exact same issue with the API.

**ex. using jquery with the Twitter API**

```
$.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=api&callback=?', function(data){
     $.each(data, function() { 
     this.id_str = this.id_str + ""; // cast integer as string to avoid PHP int to float conversion on json_decode

/* ... more API parsing code ... */
```

also make sure your capturing the `id_str` value and not the `id` value. `id_str` is perferred over `id` and is [less error prone](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/7041) when dealing with larger id's.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter IDs are classified as `64-bit integers`. Storing them as such is the best course of action. In MySQL the datatype for this is `BIGINT`.

Because different JSON interpreters struggle with parsing `BIGINT` my preferred approach is to consume the feed according to their specs:

> ...consider converting to the _str versions of IDs as soon as
>   possible.

As a JSON consumer, I would interpret the `_str` version of the id and insert this "safe" value into your BIGINT column.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't understand `2.9851634017882E+17` as an `INT` since it isn't.  It truncates the number to the longest integer it finds from the beginning of the input, which is `2`.  You need to put it in the query as an int, not in scientific notation.  Also, if that's exactly what you're getting back from Twitter, you don't even know the ID since the precision of that number doesn't go down to the ones place.

Answer (score 1):

The ID you get is a float. I would be highly surprised if twitter gives you floats as ID's.

Are you sure that the JSON object is not parsed by something that converts all integers to floats? When you fixed that then problem in saving the value will be solved.

Comment: Whoops: this just became a PHP question I guess. Twitter JSON gives back "id: 298526548477214721" but PHP's `json_decode` turns it into the `2.9851634017882E+17` form. How can I keep the original number?

Comment: the last parameter in json_decode (options) can hold the value JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING which will stop your ints from floating away.